# FileMaker 10 Pro Insert data by Asp.Net

Tags: filemaker

I am trying to insert the data in FM but get the parse error serached number of fourms with no luck.
ERROR [HY000] [DataDirect][ODBC SequeLink driver][ODBC Socket][DataDirect][ODBC FileMaker driver][FileMaker]Parse Error in SQL

```
enter code here
```

StringBuilder sbAddBarcode = new StringBuilder();
            sbAddBarcode.Append("insert into BarCode (PONumber,Description,Model,[Serial Number])");
            sbAddBarcode.Append("values");
            sbAddBarcode.Append(" ("+ barcode.PONumber + ",");
            sbAddBarcode.Append(" '" + barcode.Description +"',");
            sbAddBarcode.Append(" '" + barcode.ModelNumber +"')");
            //sbAddBarcode.Append(" '" + barcode.SerialNumber +"')");

```
        fmCommand = new OdbcCommand(sbAddBarcode.ToString(), fmcon);
        fmCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        fmCommand.Connection = fmcon;
        try
        {
            fmcon.Open();
            fmCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (OdbcException oe)
        {
            throw new Exception(oe.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            fmcon.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Echo your sbAddBarcode value. The SQL you're building does look to be invalid.